# Is a forwarded port vulnerable to exploit if there is no software listening for connections on that port?

Tags: networking, router, port, dmz

Does forwarding a port to a device (or DMZing the device) mean the device is susceptible to prodding on the opened ports even if no software listening to those ports is running on the device?

e.g.: My PC at 192.168.1.101 is running Win7 and has no software listening on port 999. But I have set up my router to forward port 999 to that PC.

If someone scans (or attempts to exploit) port 999 at my IP, will it tell the user that the port is open? Or will it only tell the user the port is open if I actually run software which listens on port 999?

Ultimately, I suppose I'm asking if a forwarded port is at all a security risk if there isn't any actual software (on that port) to exploit on the device in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few things that you'd have to worry about.

- The port will respond that it's closed, rather than not responding at all. This isn't a big deal, but it does confirm that there's a system at your IP address.
- A program that you don't expect could end up listening on that port without you knowing about it.
- If the Windows networking stack had a vulnerability that could be attacked via closed ports, it would then be remotely exploitable.

Note, though, that having a properly configured firewall on the PC would mitigate all of these issues.

Answer (score 1):

Provided that there is nothing listening on that port now OR IN THE FUTURE, the port is closed.   Theoretically, if you could guarantee that there would never be anything listening on that IP + Port combo you would not need to worry.

Ensuring the port is closed on the router provides security in 2 ways -
1.  By preventing issues caused by misconfiguration which could open the port
2.  By reducing the ability for compromised systems to communicate out  (
    this is probably irrelevant in home situations)